# cakephp plugin to make URL SEO friendly

Tags: cakephp, seo

How do I make cakephp website URL SEO friendly? Is there a plugin available for cakephp 1.2.6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First define what you mean by "SEO friendly".

Most likely this just means you want to add the name of your "object" to the URL, i.e. add a slug. You can do that without any plugin:

```
echo $html->link($record['Model']['name'], array(
    'controller' => 'foo',
    'action' => 'bar',
    $record['Model']['id'],
    Inflector::slug($record['Model']['name'])
));
// -> /foo/bar/42/the-name
```

If you require any more customized URLs, first specify what exactly you need, then use [Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration) to create these custom URLs.

Comment: by SEO friendly, I meant to name my URLs from http://www.abc.com/detail/10365 to something http://www.abc.com/detail/Page_title

Comment: @Jewel Same thing, use a slug in the URL instead of the id. You'll just need to create a slug for each record when you create it, so you can use it instead of the id to find it in the database.

Answer (score 0):

it's the only way to do it wothut any trouble...
but if you don't like id in the url, then you should take a title, remove all symbols, replace spaces with -, and write to the datebase...